# Set breakpoint for every invocation of print()

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

`pdb` allows setting a breakpoint for an [invocation of a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break).

That works for functions in your own libraries, but fails for the `print` function. The motivation behind this is exploring the runtime of a new codebase. It's usually the print statements when something interesting happens in the code.

Here is an example of it failing. Run it as `python3 print_debug.py` and execute `b print` when the debugging session starts.

```
# Filename: print_debug.py
import pdb    

pdb.set_trace()
# (Pdb++) b print
# *** The specified object 'print' is not a function or was not found along sys.path.
random_nonprint = 5    
print("I should break here")    
random_nonprint = 5    
print("I should break here again")
```

`print` is some kind of a python built in, and isn't in `sys.path` apparently. I've tried expanding `sys.path` with various python system paths i.e. `sys.path.append("usr/lib/python3.7")`. But that doesn't solve the issue.

A bonus would be to give an example on how to trigger just the `print()` invoked from certain locations. It isn't clear to me that prints from the system library would be beneficial.

Is it possible to trigger a breakpoint for every `print`?

Comment: can you create your own function that call the just `print`?

Comment: to be honest `print` is itself a kind of de-bug function. in a normal situation, if I use one, I do not use the other. However, I understand that you can have different purposes/reasons

Comment: From the comments of the other question: "if you have the py file for the module then you can, [...]"